# Python: Find subarray in array with max elements X whose sum is less than or equal to given number

Tags: python, list, sum, max

`list1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

`given_number = 7`

The problem is the following: Find subarray with maximum elements X whose sum is less than or equal to Y.
Let's say X = 2 and Y = 7, the answer will be: `[2, 4]` or `[6]`.

Now this is a widely discussed problem, I believe it's called Maximum subarray problem. However, the non-naive solution for this problem only returns the sum of the subarray, and doesn't provide the subarray itself. An example of such solution:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-subarray-sum-less-equal-given-sum/?ref=lbp

I'm wondering, is there a non-naive way of getting this optimal subarray?

EDIT: A possible answer to this problem, albeit still being naive (All credits for this goes to my friend):

1) Create all combinations of subsets with itertools:

`combs = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(list1, number_of_elements)]`

2) Sort on sum size:

`sorted_combs = sorted(combs, key=lambda x: sum(x), reverse=True)`

3) Grab the first sum under/equal to given sum:

`given_sum = 7
optimal_subset = None
for sc in sorted_combs:
    if sum(sc) <= given_sum:
        optimal_subset = sc
        break`

Comment: What you have tried to solve this? Add the code.

Comment: From what I gather, you are trying to find the maximum # of elements in list1 such that their sum is less than given_number. If you sort list1 (which your case already is), which will likely have time of nlog(n), then you can start from the bottom and select the maximum number of elements. Thus your time complexity should be nlog(n). I can't think of a better way off the top of my head.

Comment: When you update your current best highest sum, just remember the subarray that produced it and return this subarray at the end. @Sri - I think the goal is to find the subarray of consecutive elements.

Comment: @rpoleski No the fact of consecutive elements doesn't need to be taken into account

Comment: @ParthS007 Yes, I edited the question with a possible answer, albeit still being naive